# Is it possible to display mapbox coordinates inside a dynamic url?

Tags: reactjs, url, mapbox, gatsby, mapbox-gl

I'm working on a mapbox app and I need to make a dynamic URL to reflect mapbox info like lat, long and zoom level.
ex: `/?city=London&zoom=1&lat=30&lng=140`. On page load map should be centred and zoomed accordingly. How to read/write page URL?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/static-images-api/

Comment: https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/static/

Comment: The map should be dynamic not static, when the user moves the map coordinates should update as well in URL

Comment: For example like google maps dynamically displays coordinates and zoom level on url depending on position

Comment: https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11.html?access_token=123456#11.58/40.4299/-3.6376 where 123456 is your access token

Comment: Otherwise you'd have to program a script that would parse the url and pass the params over to mapboxgl.Map constructor or something like that

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after. Know any template app which uses one?

Answer (score 3):

Just activate the `hash : true` in the Map initial settings

```js
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11',
            center: [128, 47],
            zoom: 16.5,
            pitch: 60,
            hash: true // just add this
        });
```

It’s not the same param names but you’ll have the same information

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to convert the hash format to a non hash one